# How to make post data in a three many to many models with flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have three models in  a many to many relational conception between the three tables sources categories and keywords:

```
class SourceDevice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "source_devices"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    source_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("sources.id"), nullable=False)
    categorie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("categories.id"), nullable=False)
    keyword_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("keywords.id"), nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint(source_id, categorie_id, keyword_id),)

    sources = db.relationship("Sources", back_populates="source_devices")
    categories = db.relationship("Categories", back_populates="source_devices")
    keywords = db.relationship("Keywords", back_populates="source_devices")

class Sources(db.Model,UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "sources"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    source = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    #catgeorie_id =  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    source_devices  = db.relationship('SourceDevice', back_populates='sources')
    #categories = db.relationship('Categories', secondary=categories_sources, lazy='subquery',
    #    backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True))
    def serialize(self):
        return {'id': self.id,
                'source': self.source,
                'user_id': self.user_id,
                'date_created': self.date_created,
       }

class Categories(db.Model,UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "categories"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    #source_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sources.id'))
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    #keyword = db.relationship('Keywords', backref='categorie', lazy='dynamic')
    source_devices  = db.relationship('SourceDevice', back_populates='categories')
    def serialize(self):
        return {'id': self.id,
                'categorie': self.category,
                'date_created': self.date_created,
                 }


class Keywords(db.Model,UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "keywords"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    source_devices  = db.relationship('SourceDevice', back_populates='keywords')

    def serialize(self):
        return {'id': self.id,
                'keyword': self.word,
                 'date_created': self.date_created,

                }
```

I found this link helpful:
[Many-to-Many with three tables relating with each other (SqlAlchemy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920701/many-to-many-with-three-tables-relating-with-each-other-sqlalchemy)
As I understand I have to use the code below to add ne keywords based on an existant sources and an existant categorie:

```
categorie = db.session.query(Categories).filter(Categories.category == "Bricolage").first()
source = db.session.query(Sources).filter(Sources.source == "Amazon").first()
keyword = db.session.query(Keywords).filter(Keywords.keyword == "Marteau").first()
assoc = SourceDevice(sources=source, categories=categorie, keywords=keyword)
db.session.add(assoc)
db.session.commit()
```

But how to add a categorie only based on a source without having to put a keywords.
Please also correct me if I had done a mistake in the models.

Thanks.

Comment: `assoc =SourceDevice(source_id = source.id, categorie_id = categorie.id, keyword_id=keyword.id)` , you need to add the value which are required in db not the whole object

Comment: @sahasrara62 Can I remove in the sources_devices table the condition not nullable for all the id?

Comment: depend on what you want to achive, if adding nullable work with your logic then it is good, else no

Comment: @sahasrara62 it works. Thanks

Comment: adding solution in answer, for future reference

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide the data in your Source model class according to the class field.

```
assoc =SourceDevice(source_id = source.id, categorie_id = categorie.id, keyword_id=keyword.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the solution to one category based on a source in a three many to many conception:

```
categorie = db.session.query(Categories).filter(Categories.category == a given categoy).first()
source = db.session.query(Sources).filter(Sources.source == a given source ).first()

assoc = SourceDevice(sources=source, categories=categorie )
db.session.add(assoc)
db.session.commit()
```

Make sure to add at least two of the id_source, id_category and id_category  of the SourceDevice model as nullable.