# SQLAlchemy association table with more than two foreignkeys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 4 tables, `Person`, `Video`, `Alias`, and an association table `video_person_association_table` between videos and people.

Each person has aliases. For example "Clark Kent" is a person. One of his aliases is "Superman" another one is "Kal-El"

There is a One to Many relationship between A person and their aliases like so:

```py
class Person(Base):
    #... other class stuff

    aliases: ["Alias"] = relationship("Alias", back_populates="person")


class Alias(Base):
    #... other class stuff

    person_id: int = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = relationship("Person", back_populates="aliases")
```

Also, a person can have many videos and a video can have many people, so the relationship between videos and people is many to many:

```py
class Person(Base):
    #... other class stuff

   videos: ["Video"] = relationship("Video", secondary=video_person_association_table, back_populates="people")

class Video(Base):
    #... other class stuff
    people: list["Person"] = relationship("Person", secondary=video_person_association_table, back_populates="videos")

video_person_association_table = Table("video_person_association_table",
                                       Base.metadata,
                                       Column('video_id', ForeignKey('video.id'), primary_key=True),
                                       Column('person_id', ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
                                       )
```

And this works fine. However, I want to add a 3rd column in the association table, like so:

```py
video_person_association_table = Table("video_person_association_table",
                                       Base.metadata,
                                       Column('video_id', ForeignKey('video.id'), primary_key=True),
                                       Column('person_id', ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True),
                                       Column('alias_id', ForeignKey('alias.id'), primary_key=True)
                                       )
```

I want to do this because the way I associate people with videos is through their aliases.

For example, a video called: "It's a bird, it's a plane, No! It's Superman" will be associated with the alias "Superman". Another video "Kal-El the last son of Krypton" will be associated
using the alias "Kal-El"

If the Aliases table looks like this:

| id | person_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Clark Kent |
| 2 | 1 | Superman |
| 3 | 1 | Kal-El |

And People table looks like this:
| id | birthday|
|:----:|:------:|
| 1  | 1938|

And Videos table looks like this:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | It's a bird, it's a plane, No! It's Superman |
| 2 | Kal-El the last son of Krypton |
| 3 | Clark Kent receives an award for excellence in journalism |

I want the association table to look like this:

| video_id | person_id | alias_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

The reason I want it this way, is I want to keep the information of why a certain video was associated with a certain person. So to this end I want to store the id of the alias I used to do the association.

I also need the person id there to make the queries simpler. If the person id wasn't there and I wanted to see what people were associated with a certain video I need to join the video to the alias and then join the alias to people.

The problem with this though is when I try to run SqlAlchemy and insert something in this table I get:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: video_person_association_table.alias_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO video_person_association_table (video_id, person_id) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ((1, 1), (1, 2))]
```

The problem here isn't the NOT NULL constraint. It's that it only tries to insert two values into the association table. Is there a way to configure the relationship such that it will use 3 columns instead of 2?

I know there's an [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) But it's for more complex scenarios where you need to store extra information besides Foreign Keys on the association table. But I only need Foreign keys.

Comment: I might give cyclical problems and duplicating relationships. You should not create the third table. Instead create a view or make the join when you are going to use it. You are on the wrong track on creating redundant table. I have tried similar things before it always fails because it is the wrong way to model the data.

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen "You should not create the third table. " What do you mean? A third table is the standard way to make Many to Many relationships between two tables. 

Anyway, do you have a better idea of how a similar objective can be achieved in the correct way?

Comment: If you want the alias_id combination video_id you should make as a join of the video_person_association_table and the alias table. So basically stay with the stucture of only two primary keys and join

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen I posted a possible solution, but I'm not sure if it's better than your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for returning and interesting suggestion. Do you need an (ondelete="CASCADE")? can you add a Person without an Alias? I think the original suggestion is more simple and I think you will run into less problems in the long run by just joining. Just out of queriousity what operation is that is difficult with the original setup?

Comment: "Do you need an (ondelete="CASCADE")?" I think so. I didn't test deleting yet. "can you add a Person without an Alias?" No. This is the intention. Each person must have an alias. It's easy to allow this, just to set `alias_id` column in the `VideoPersonAssociation` object to be able to be nullable. And remove the unique constraint on this column.

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen "Just out of queriousity what operation is that is difficult with the original setup?" The original setup I had was associating Videos only with Aliases and associating Aliases with People. So each time I wanted to get people from a video I had to do `session.query(Video).join(Video.aliases).join(Alias.Person)` this resulted in rather convoluted queries and it actually made it harder to think about how to construct queries.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing is using an [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) with [Association Proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) mostly using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920701/many-to-many-with-three-tables-relating-with-each-other-sqlalchemy) SO question.

Association Object:

```py
class VideoPersonAssociation(Base):
    """Represents an association between a Person and a video"""
    __tablename__ = 'video_person'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    video_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('video.id'), nullable=False)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'), nullable=False)
    alias_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('alias.id'), nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(video_id, person_id, alias_id),)

    video = relationship("Video", back_populates="people_association_objects")
    person = relationship("Person", back_populates="videos_association_objects")
    alias = relationship("Alias")
```

Video class:

```py
class Video(Base):
#... other class variables

    #relationship that ties to VideoTagAssociation *video_id* foreign key. This is filled with <VideoTagAssociation objects>
    people_association_objects: list["Person"] = relationship("VideoPersonAssociation", back_populates="video")

    #proxies the people_association_objects relationship to the *person* field of VideoTagAssociation. (Allows us to do `Video.people` instead of `Video.people_association_objects.person`)
    people = association_proxy('people_association_objects', 'person')

    #relationship that ties to VideoTagAssociation *alias_id* foreign key. This is filled with <VideoTagAssociation objects> too
    #viewonly=True means that we do not intend to set aliases through this field
    people_aliases_association_objects: list["Alias"] = relationship("VideoPersonAssociation", viewonly=True)

    #same as the people proxy. Allows us to do `for alias in video.people_aliases: print(alias)` instead of 'for x in video.people_aliases_association_objects: print(x.alias)'
    people_aliases = association_proxy('people_aliases_association_objects', 'alias')
```

Person Class:

```py
class Person(Base):
#... other class variables

   #works the same way as above... We don't care about aliases id in Person. Only in Video. This why we don't have alias fields here.

    videos_association_objects: list["Video"] = relationship("VideoPersonAssociation", back_populates="person")

    videos = association_proxy('videos_association_objects', 'video')
```

This works rather well, but you need to manually enter the information in the association object like this:

```py
clark = Person(birth_year=1937)

alias_clark_kent = Alias(name="Clark Kent")
alias_superman = Alias(name="Superman")
alias_Kal_El = Alias(name="Kal El")

clark.aliases.append(alias_clark_kent)
clark.aliases.append(alias_superman)
clark.aliases.append(alias_Kal_El)

video = Video(title="It's a bird, it's a plane, it's Superman")

session.add(video)
session.add(clark)
session.commit()

association = VideoPersonAssociation(video=video,person=clark,alias=alias_superman)

session.add(association)
session.commit()

#now we can do:

loaded_video = session.query(Video).filter(Video.title="It's a bird, it's a plane, it's Superman").first()


print(loaded_video.people[0].birth_year)

# will print 1937

print(loaded_video.people_aliases[0].name)

# will print "Superman"


#also we can do this
results = session.query(Video).filter(Video.people_aliases.any(Alias.name.like("%Super%"))).all()

#results will be all the videos that have a person alias like "Super"
```

## Conclusion:

I'm not sure this method is better than what @Peter Mølgaard Pallesen suggested. (Just make an additional association table and an extra join). I've included this answer because it does what I asked at the beginning, but I'm not sure that going further I'll use this instead of what Peter suggested.

Comment: Can you include your `Alias` class, I'm curious as if there are any relationships in there